# git hangs up unexpectedly (but the push works)

Tags: git, ssh

I'm encountering some strange behavior so I'm hoping someone can help shed some light on this. When I do a *git push*, it ends with a "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" but checking the git logs and the remote repo seems to indicate the push went through fine. Rerunning the *git push* returns "Everything is up to date".

So a little background, I have dropbear and git installed on a Palm Pre and am trying to commit changes to a repo on gitorious. Since dropbear is kind of screwy, I had to create a shell script (called sssh) that does the equivalent of

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $*
```

as dropbear will not automatically scan for the publickey. Additionally, I have defined GIT_SSH to be /opt/bin/sssh.

So at this point, everything *seems* to work but I am not sure why the "fatal" message keeps popping up. Any ideas?

Update: Edited to show what I have in .git/config.

```
root@castle:/opt/src/modifications# cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitorious.org:webos-internals/modifications.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "all"]
    url = git@gitorious.org:webos-internals/modifications.git
    url = git@github.com:jauderho/webos-hacks.git
```

Comment: I've just run into this problem on an OpenWRT box.  I've got an email I'm going to send to the dropbear mailing list once I've subscribed detailing this problem.  I don't really see any reference to this problem in a place the dropbear developers would see it. It also doesn't come up in their commit log.

Lastly one issue is that post-receive hooks don't run. So while refs and objects get pushed, hooks aren't running which is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess (you should probably ask on the [Git For Human Beings Mailinglist](https://Groups.Google.Com/group/git-users/) or if that doesn't help the developer mailinglist (git@vger.kernel.org)).

My guess is, that either Dropbear itself or your wrapper script exits in such a way that Git thinks there is something wrong with the connection. It might be something as trivial as Git trying to pattern match on some string returned by OpenSSH that is not 100% identical on Dropbear, or a wrong exit code, or something like that.

Comment: git@vger.kernel.org is the git mailing list, it's not supposed to be the 'developer-only' mailing list or anything.

Comment: I just tried strace git push origin master and noticed that for some reason .git/refs/remotes/origin/master was missing. I've added that back in but does not seem to make a difference. Will ask the mailing list though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use another ssh client, you have the same error?

I think is maybe a problem with dropbear than a problem with Git.

The refs are for using `git push origin master` instead of `git push ssh://server/path/to/git/repository master`

Comment: It supposedly works fine with openssh. The problem of needing a shell script in the first place is because dropbear does not look for a keyfile in a default location. I'll update the original post with what I have in .git/config

Answer (score 0):

I get errors with post-commit hooks in Mercurial that make it seem like the transaction failed, but it still succeeds.

Could be something similar.